# how to display content of text file in the browser using watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to save the results of my test in the log_file.txt and I want it to display in the browser. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance,

Helfe

Comment: Did you try `browser.goto '...full path/log_file.txt'`?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev .. not yet sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write out the text file in html format (internally) and use a .html extension on the file. (then you can format it and make it look pretty)

or just point the browser at the full path of the file including the extension, most browsers should render it, even if it is not pretty.